# Div's animating as one, instead of individually

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I'm trying to make a Material Design like animation on my website. As you can see, when I press the button, each one of them animates, instead of animating only the one I pressed. EDIT: After I made the gif, I managed to get a smooth animation on them, but they still act as one. http://oi59.tinypic.com/29ek9wx.jpg This is the animation that I get.
Here's my code for the Query:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var toggleState = true;
    $('.show').on("click", function() {
        if(toggleState) {
            $(this).find('svg').each(function(){
                $(this).css({
                    transform: "rotate(180deg)"
                });
            });
            $(document).find('.box').each(function(){
                $(this).css({
                    height: "+=200"
                },1000);
            });
        } else {
            $(this).find('svg').each(function(){
                $(this).animate({
                    transform: "rotate(+=180deg)",
                });
            });
            $(document).find('.box').each(function(){
                $(this).css({
                    height: "240" // this is the default height
                },1000);
            });
        }
        toggleState = !toggleState;
    });
});
// .show is the container of the svg(the arrow). .box is the container of the whole thing
```

PS: I managed to get a smooth animation after making the .gif, The only problem is them acting as one.
PS2: Don't mind the cursor.

Even more code.

```
<div class="fluid-layout">
    <article class="box-wrapper">
        <section class="box">
            <div class="main-color" id="red">
            </div>
            <div class="show">
                <svg class="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="36" height="36" viewBox="0 0 36 36">
                    <path d="M18 12l-9 9 2.12 2.12 6.88-6.88 6.88 6.88 2.12-2.12z"/>
                    <path d="M0 0h36v36h-36z" fill="none"/>
                </svg>
            </div>
        </section
        ><section class="box">
            <div class="main-color" id="pink">
            </div>
            <div class="show">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="36" height="36" viewBox="0 0 36 36">
                    <path d="M18 12l-9 9 2.12 2.12 6.88-6.88 6.88 6.88 2.12-2.12z"/>
                    <path d="M0 0h36v36h-36z" fill="none"/>
                </svg>
            </div>
        </section
        ><section class="box">
            <div class="main-color" id="purple">
            </div>
            <div class="show">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="36" height="36" viewBox="0 0 36 36">
                    <path d="M18 12l-9 9 2.12 2.12 6.88-6.88 6.88 6.88 2.12-2.12z"/>
                    <path d="M0 0h36v36h-36z" fill="none"/>
                </svg>
            </div>
        </section
        >
    </article>
</div>
```

Comment: can you put your code in a jsfiddle it would make it easy to debug / give feedback. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5dLyqsyu/2/

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem stems from the code here

```
 $(document).find('.box').each(function(){
            $(this).css({
                height: "240" // this is the default height
            },1000);
```

and

```
$(document).find('.box').each(function(){
            $(this).css({
                height: "+=200"
            },1000);
        });
```

You are searching the document for the box class and applying css to all of those boxes at the same time. I could help you fix the problem if I knew your html structure for those boxes.

see http://api.jquery.com/closest/ for documentation relating to closest()

EDIT:

replacing

```
$(document).find('.box').each(function(){
```

with

```
$(this).closest('.color-group').each(function(){
```

Will help and solve that particular problem. see http://jsfiddle.net/FERMIS/5dLyqsyu/3/

However the boxes will now move weirdly. To fix that you need to do some CSS work.

remove

```
display: table-cell;
```

from

```
.fluid-layout .color-group .main-color span {
```

Then add a new block of CSS to recenter the text that was messed up by removing the previous line of CSS

```
.main-color span{
    display:block;
    line-height: 5em; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FERMIS/5dLyqsyu/4/

Comment: Any ideas? Added the fiddle. Look below your comment.

Comment: Working on it, give me a few minuets =)

Comment: It does help somehow. But any way of making it not affect the rest of the page? This could work on mobile, since only one box will be displayed per line, but on bigger screens however..

Comment: Remove "display: table-cell;" from the CSS, sorry to take so long to get back to you. This will mess up the text a little in the boxes but they wont move like they did before.

Comment: will do, no problem, made a version using only one column, instead of 3, but will try that out when I have time!